# How do they film continuous blood pooling?

Tags: film-techniques

I have seen in **American Sniper**, **Dead-7** and **Carrie** that when someone is killed, they are laying on the ground with blood leaking out of their back or somewhere else on the body.

The puddle continuously grows with few signs of slowing down. This is obviously not CGI because it is a real liquid (may not be real blood as that would spark an emergency in real life).

I have seen in American Sniper that when the protagonist kills yet another enemy, they are filmed hitting the ground and blood starts pooling around their body.

**In Carrie:** In the dance room where Carrie sets her powers loose and kills a lot of teenagers in the process, there are a few that hit the ground with blood pooling under their bodies. Sometimes they would be on their side with blood coming out.

**In Dead 7:** Kimono and the other six killed lots of zombies. Some of the six were killed in the process as well before they came to Apocalypta to kill her. They were filmed hitting the ground dead with blood pooling around them.

I am not sure how they film this as they are wearing thin shirts for these scenes, and not only that, but the characters also have blood (obviously fake) only just dripping out of the side of their mouths (an indicator they have a ruptured and wounded stomach or lung (in this case the blood would be pink and frothy).

**What is the film technique that allows this to happen?**

Comment: I'm confused by the analysis that "This is obviously not CGI because it is a real liquid". I think I know what you're getting at, but these days not only can CGI look **really** convincing, but "real liquid" can be depicted using CGI (and it's not exactly uncommon).

Comment: How good does CGI get these days - watch The Jungle Book.

Comment: Oops, too late to edit in the link - [Making of Jungle Book](https://youtu.be/vkNArCG80Bg) - essentially, only Mowgli is real in any shot.

Comment: Easy: We lose more extras this way...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With a reference to [my answer here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/72294/27264), the continuous blood pooling is easy to film by passing a small pipe through the performer's clothing and this pipe can be connected to a container, either plastic or something that can be hidden easily, with a liquid similar to blood (as mentioned in answers to [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/24467/27264)). Remember someone on set can also use a pump to show blood pumping out of the performer's body.

In such scenes, we see the performer lying on the ground. This pipe can easily be hidden under them inside their clothing.

Comment: Note that in some scenes, the pipes need not be connected to the body, but can be connected to the blood pond