# How is arterial blood spray filmed?

Tags: film-techniques, effects

In **Dead 7**, **Carrie** and other movies, there have been some scenes where an artery has been severed and an open wound is visible causing an artierial spray coming from inside the wound.

I am sure this may be CGI or whatever, and for the wound, I have no idea, but there doesn't seem to be any fake blood tubes coming from the area of the spray.

The blood just squirts and squirts. In Dead y, Apocalypta slits a mans throat when he wants to join her and it results in arterial spray.

Also in an episode of **The walking dead** where the cannibals have got hold of some survivors, they slit the survivors throats over a trough, resulting in arterial spray.

**How is this filmed?**

Comment: See [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/72294/27264) and above linked question to get an idea how can it be done. Though method may differ for each film maker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a video that suggests how this might be done.

A prosthetic neck 'sleeve' is placed over our victim's own neck which, underneath, has tubing connected to a pump.

When the prosthetic is 'slashed', the prop man at the end of the tube pumps blood up and out. You can see him in the left background.

also...